# How many times in total has Earth formed a super continent?

Tags: plate-tectonics, earth-history

I know there was a Pangaea at one point in history that broke into the continents of today, but I could have sworn there was another instance in Earth's history that there was a super continent, maybe even more, so how many in total?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinent

Answer (score 2):

According to a review by [Nance & Murphy (2013)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1674987112001570?via%3Dihub), there are five known supercontinents, from the most recent to the most ancient:

- Pangea (of course)
- Pannotia (though [it depends on how you define supercontinent](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/R_Nance/publication/323514106_Supercontinents_and_the_case_for_Pannotia/links/5a9d98e84585155dc184bf6d/Supercontinents-and-the-case-for-Pannotia.pdf)), ca. 600 Ma
- Rodinia, breakup at ca. 750 Ma (see e. g. [Torsvik, 2003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1083469))
- Columbia (also called Nuna), ca. 1.6 Ga
- Kenorland, ca. 2.7 Ga

Some additional ones such as Vaalbara in the Archean are still mostly speculative.